# Custom Predicate Evaluation in Flink gives java.io.NotSerializableException:

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, predicate

I have a CustomPredicate that evaluates an expression to be `true` or `false`. A few months back, the code was working just fine.

Now, I get the following exception even before the Flink job is submitted. Below are details about the exception:

```
org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: java.util.function.Predicate$$Lambda$167/20853837@390a07a0 is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
```

The above exception is caused by:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.function.Predicate$$Lambda$167/20853837
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
        at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:632)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:143)
        ... 28 more
```

Below is the `CustomPredicate`:

```
public class CustomPredicate implements Predicate<RowMapPair>, Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3122121231213145L;

  private final String column;
  private final String value;

  @Override
  public boolean test(RowMapPair rowMapPair) {
    MapState<String, Pair> mapState = rowMapPair.getMapState();
    Row row = rowMapPair.getRow();
    String id = String.valueOf(row.getFieldAs("_id"));
    String key = String.join("__", id, column);

    String curVal = null;
    try {
      Pair val = mapState.get(key);
      log.debug("** val: {}", mapState.get(key));
      if (Objects.nonNull(val)) {
        curVal = String.valueOf(val.getValue());
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return curVal.equalsIgnoreCase(value);
  }
}
```

`RowMapMair` looks like this:

```
public class RowMapPair implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 31213145L;
  private MapState<String, Pair> mapState;
  private Row row;
}
```

The caller function does this:

```
return new CustomPredicate(column, stringValue.getValue());
```

Has anyone faced this issue before? I tried with different versions of Flink: `1.14.5`, `1.14.3` and `1.14.0`. Nothing works for some reason.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

### General Flink Serialization Advice

Flink falls back to use the Kryo Java serialization framework. It is very general and not super robust. You have quite complex objects. Try to make them flatter.

If you are using Row that is already kind of a HashMap that is serializable. That is a good place to put values.

You can use the class `org.apache.flink.table.data.GenericRowData`. That is easy to work with.